# ZFS Status Graph

Tags: opensolaris, zfs, graphical-user-interface

In many of the Sun videos about ZFS I see them using some kind of graphing program to show the read write IO of the disks.

ie: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGIwg6ye1gE

See them red and green bars?

What is that program and is it in OpenSolaris?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a ZFS web based interface, but it doesn't provide any analytical insight into system. What you're probably seeing up there in the demo is DTrace data being plotted in real time. You could even do that on your own with a dtrace and gnuplot script.

Comment: There is no need to use dtrace to get kernel statistics, kstat is the API to use. It has interfaces with C, shell scripting, perl, java, python ...

Comment: Seems that DTrace is the interface of choice when it comes to the IO subsystem.

Comment: In some cases it might but not in that particular one. Using dtrace to compute input and output load would likely be doable with dtrace but quite inefficient as these statistics are already managed by the kernel and easily available through kstat.

Comment: Thx! very informative.

Answer (score 2):

This application is likely based on kernel statistics retrieved through the kstat interface.

Have a look at [iobar](http://jlliagre.free.fr/jllTools/readme.html#iobar) for a similar tool.